# PHP Directory Permissions Check

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that needs to check the permissions on a directory to make sure it is writable.  What I have so far is:

```
$perms = substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($folder)), -4);
if ($perms == "0777" || is_writable('temp'.DS)) 
{
    //code here
}
```

Is this a sufficient check?

Comment: Really, you only need is_writeable(), and maybe is_directory(). It's either writeable, or it isn't, so there's no need to check the individual o/g/a flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP's `is_writable()` should be sufficient.  Below is the description from the PHP manual:

> The filename argument may be a directory name allowing you to check if
>   a directory is writable.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php for more details.

Comment: So PHP's is_writable is a shortcut to see if a directory has the correct permissions for a file to be created in it.

Answer (score 8):

There's no need to check the permissions manually, it's enough to use use [`is_writable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) and [`is_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php):

```
if (is_dir($myDir) && is_writable($myDir)){
   //do stuff
}
```