# PHP is_writable() to check if file can be written?

Tags: php, file, directory, writable

I've read that I can use [is_writable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285045/php-directory-permissions-check) to check if a folder or a file is writable.

**How do I check if a file can be written to a folder?**

1. Do I check the folder and if the folder is writable? Then the file is allowed to be put into that folder?
2. What if the file has been written to the folder, how do I check if that is writable again (edited)? Do I need to? If so, do I check the file instead of the folder?
3. Is it a safe method (correct) to do it?

Comment: Did you read the official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP function `is_writable` is exactly for this purpose. If you want to check if file is still writable after you've written the file, you can use the same function.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation as linked in the question you pointed to. `is_writable()` is working on files and directories.

But mind: If you have code like this:

```
if (is_writeable("foo.txt")) {
    $fp = fopen("foo.txt", "w");
    /* ...*/
}
```

This might still fail. For instance there might be a lock or a race condition (permissions change between the two commands). Better simply try to open and then handle the error.

```
$fp = @fopen("foo.txt", "w");
if (!$fp) { 
    report_error_in_some_way();
}
```

Comment: Mh, PHP4 File functions.

Comment: Using the @ operator is asking for trouble.. imagine your report_error_in_some_way() function is broken, you'll have a very hard time finding the real issue. Never ever use the @ operator.